# Access violation error while attempting to transfer a large file using HTTP / REST server

Tags: c++, rest, http, file-transfer

Using a `REST` library, I am trying to set it up as a file sharing server, but am running into issues when transferring large files.

As I understand it, the file transfer should mean opening a stream to the file, getting its buffer in a `stringstream`,then write it within a response body. This seems to work with small files of only a few bytes or `KB`, but anything larger fails.

```
    std::string filePath = "some_accessible_file";
    struct stat st;
    if(stat(filePath.c_str(), &st) != 0)
    {
        //handle it
    }
    size_t fileSize = st.st_size;
    std::streamsize sstreamSize = fileSize;
    std::fstream str; 
    str.open(filePath.c_str(), std::ios::in);
    std::ostringstream sstream;
    sstream << str.rdbuf();
    const std::string str1(sstream.str());
    const char* ptr = str1.c_str();
    response.headers().add(("Content-Type"), ("application/octet-stream"));
    response.headers().add(("Content-Length"), fileSize);
    if (auto resp = request.respond(std::move(response))) //respond returns shared pointer to respond type 
    {
                        
        resp->write(ptr, sstreamSize ); //Access violation for large files
        
    }
```

Not quite sure why large files would fail. Does file type make a difference? I was able to transfer small text files etc. but a small pdf failed...

Comment: What is `a` here? Also add `std::ios::binary` to the constructor of `str`, if only to indicate that it might return binary data.

Comment: Oops, that was the streamsize. Corrected now..

Comment: Just for paranoia's sake, can you check if `sstreamSize == str1.size()`? Also, are you on Windows by any chance?

Comment: @Botje   hmm...they are not same. e.g. sstreamsize is the actual file size (around 1 mb), whereas str1.size() simply gives 600...in the code, if I give resp->write(ptr, str1.size()), there is no error, but the file being downloaded is only 600 bytes (1 KB), so incorrectly written. Not sure where the issue is. Both client and server are on windows.

Comment: And you *are* reading in binary mode, right?

Comment: I am. `std::fstream str; str.open(filePath.c_str(), std::ios::in, std::ios::binary);`

Comment: No, that should be `str.open(filePath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary)` If you read a binary file in text mode, Windows will stop as soon as it sees a 0x1A character.

Comment: @Botje  Ah, yes. That was indeed the issue. Thanks, that seems to have solved the problem. If you write it out as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this error was `std::fstream` not reading the entire file because it was opened in text mode. In windows, this makes reading stop at a end of file (0x1A) character.

The fix is to open the file in `std::ios::binary` mode.